# Apollo client delete cache of a specific query

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

How is it possible to delete the cache of a specific query on Apollo Client in TS and don't touch the other cache?

The `cache.modify` has an `INVALIDATE` option but I cannot find it for `cache.updateQuery`